# Auto Refresh Spotfire Webplayer

Tags: tibco, spotfire

I just recently develop report with Tibco Spotfire. This tool have quite good performance for reporting. But i had a problem to make my report realtime.

Is there any way to make it realtime? or at least i can make it auto refresh?

Thank you,
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Scheduled Updates might be what you are looking for.

What are Scheduled Updates? Scheduled updates are a way to reduce the time it takes for a user to open certain analysis files. This is done by preloading analysis files on the Spotfire Web Player server before a user attempts to open them. Scheduled updates are most effective if you have certain analysis files with linked data (from an information link or any other linkable data source), that are updated regularly with large amounts of new data. Often such updates occur during the night, and the following morning users want to open the corresponding analysis files to view the latest data. If that data has already been preloaded the analysis will open much faster. The same goes for a large analysis with lots of data, that users might open several times during the day to quickly check for figures or similar. Instead of having to load this into memory every time a user opens the analysis, you can make sure this analysis is always available in memory, ensuring a rapid response for the users.

TIBCO Spotfire® Web Player 4.5 69 (103) http://stn.spotfire.com/pdfud/TIB_SpotWebPlay_InstallationManual.pdf

Comment: User asked to make the report real-time. Scheduled updates involves caching the file on server to make it fast for a given period so no updates are made.

Answer (score 1):

If your data source/table is linked and you would like to refresh without reopening your file, you can attach a script to a button that can do this.

[Spotfire manual: To add a script action link or button to the text area](http://stn.spotfire.com/spotfire_client_help/text/text_using_scripts_in_the_text_area.htm)

[Spotfire manual: Script to refresh table](http://stn.spotfire.com/spotfire_client_help/text/text_ironpython_example_scripts.htm)

```
# Example script that refreshes a table driven by
# a calculation, a data function
# or an information link loaded on demand.
# The script takes a parameter "table" of type DataTable

if table.IsRefreshable and table.NeedsRefresh:
   table.Refresh()
```